# Semantic-ui install fail npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I get the following error when trying to install `semantic-ui` via `npm` for fresh project.

```
$ node -v
v16.14.0
$ npm -v
8.10.0
```

```
$ npm i semantic-ui
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/indikau/workspace/learning/web_design/semantic_ui/Tutorial/13_theming/node_modules/semantic-ui
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c gulp install
npm ERR! Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/indikau/workspace/learning/web_design/semantic_ui/Tutorial/13_theming/node_modules/del/index.js from /home/indikau/workspace/learning/web_design/semantic_ui/Tutorial/13_theming/node_modules/semantic-ui/tasks/clean.js not supported.
npm ERR! Instead change the require of index.js in /home/indikau/workspace/learning/web_design/semantic_ui/Tutorial/13_theming/node_modules/semantic-ui/tasks/clean.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/indikau/workspace/learning/web_design/semantic_ui/Tutorial/13_theming/node_modules/semantic-ui/tasks/clean.js:8:12)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/indikau/workspace/learning/web_design/semantic_ui/Tutorial/13_theming/node_modules/semantic-ui/gulpfile.js:21:18)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/indikau/.npm/_logs/2022-10-20T01_40_53_411Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: The community fork [Fomantic-UI](https://fomantic-ui.com) has this (and more) fixed. Would that be an option?

Answer (score 4):

This is related to the `del` package being updated to ESM-only. You can fix this by forcing a resolution of del@6.1 (rather than 7.x) in your package.json.

I use yarn which has this built in. I believe you must use a package like this for npm https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions.